# Baking yeast breads in gas oven?

Tags: bread

There are only 3 rack settings in my gas oven.  I have baked on the top rack and my bread is raw. Which one should I use to cook at 350f for 35-40 min.

Comment: Be sure the oven is pre-heated and up to or slightly above baking temperature. Adjust your baking time, based on the internal temperature of the bread, not just on a recipe. Allow cooling time before cutting, to have the bread continue baking.

Answer (score 1):

I have a gas oven as well, and have found that baking on the middle rack, using a pizza stone helps bread bake more evenly. Additionally, as User22259 suggested, adjusting the baking time until the internal temp of the bread reaches about 220-degrees will get you a perfect product every time.

Comment: Is 220 degrees a typo?  That cannot be correct in either F or C

Comment: 200 F or 202 F sound indeed like a possible temperature, not 220

Answer (score -1):

Turn the temperature up. 350F is not hot enough for bread -- try something more like 400F (200C). Also, check that your oven calibration is accurate -- see [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/37470/can-i-test-my-oven-temperature-without-an-oven-thermometer) for ways to check it.

Comment: I regularly bake bread at 175 Celsius, there is nothing wrong with it.